# automatically delete certain characters from input box while user is typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to validate a form and the input box I'm working on should only consist of numbers. If a user starts typing any letters I want them to automatically delete and obviously if they type numbers it shouldn't delete.

here is my js:

```
var defaultValue = 10; 

$(document).ready(function() {

      $('#donation-amount').keyup(function() {
      if($(this).val()) {
         $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
    } else {
        $('#display-amount').text(defaultValue);
       $("#default").addClass('active');
       $("#btn2").removeClass('active');
       $("#btn3").removeClass('active');
    }
        if (isNaN( $(this).val() )) {
        console.log("false")
        } else {
        console.log("true")
        }

      });
     $( ".selectvalue" ).click(function() {
        $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
     });

    $(".buttons .btn").click(function(){
        $(".buttons .btn").removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
    });
    $('#display-amount').text($('#default').val());

});
```

and here is my html:

```
 <input type="Custom" name="donation-amount" class="inpt-first form-control" id="donation-amount" onclick="if(this.defaultValue == this.value) this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="Custom">
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting non-numeric characters, just ignore them in the first place, or define the input type as `number`.

[HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Answer (score 0):

You want this ? [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gxwh89tj/1/)

```
var defaultValue = 10; 

$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#donation-amount').keyup(function() {
        // check if numbers are type
        var reg = /^\d+$/;
        if(reg.test($(this).val())) {
          $('#donation-amount').val($(this).val());
            } else {
         $('#donation-amount').val(defaultValue);

            }      
      });
});
```

Comment: this is great! but do you know how I get the value back into the input box instead of the 10 if a user types letters the 10 appears and I want Custom to appear and when I try and delete it it won't let me

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you exactly wants. Can you precise it ?

Comment: yeah. so when I type a number in the input field it displays fine but when I type a letter, the default value I have set of 10 var defaultValue = 10;  appears in the input box and when I try to delete the 10 it doesn't delete. instead of 10 showing up I would like the value  of my input box to appear instead. value="Custom Hopefully this was explained better

Comment: It works fine, but I also want to allow alphabetical characters and dot?

Comment: How could i customize it

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take advantage of HTML5's `<input type="number">`. However, if that doesn't work for your situation or isn't desirable you may want to try using jQuery's `keydown()` function.

**HTML**

`<input id="inputField" type="text">`

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $("#inputField").keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.which != 0 && e.which != 8 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            $("#quantity").html('').append();
        }
    });
});
```

This checks that keys firing the event are numeric and within the numeric keys assignment range. If the keys firing the event do not match these conditions then no output is given. However, if the input qualifies as within the numeric range it will be added (`append()`) to the input field itself.

It is worth noting that this can be achieved using standard JavaScript: `window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {});`